# How to copy file from USB,HDD to Ubuntu

Tags: usb

i just mount USB,HDD to Ubuntu.
After that i click Accessories - File Manager PCManFM at Left Corner
But i don't see any USB popup or New Folder.

i use LXDE
[image]

Comment: How did you mount drives?

Comment: i just bring USB 16GB to USB Port at Case. Physical.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-) What do you mean by "to Ubuntu"  Do you mean to copy files from USB to HDD???

Comment: Yes. Copy file from USB or HDD2 to HDD(Installed Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

**Manual Mount**

`sudo lsblk`

`sudo mkdir /media/USB`

`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/USB -o udi=1001`

***Here assumes `/dev/sdb1` is your device and `1001` is user id***

Comment: I use NTFS USB , any problem with this type ?

Comment: What File system should be format for usb ? (NTFS,FAT,FAT32,exFAT)

Comment: Format the partition with VFAT `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1`